# Visual Studio std::complex Performance

Tags: c++

I am having a performance problem using std::complex. I am developing on AMD architecture, Visual Studio 2013 64-bit, release mode.

When I use the built-in complex operator * this code runs in > 92 milliseconds (I have simplified it but this was in a loop and I was averaging results). If I use the code that I have commented out below, which essentially is a hand-coded version of complex multiply it runs in about 6 milliseconds.  complex numbers are basic building blocks, I use them everyday as a developer in scientific computing so I would have thought the performance would be much better than this. I can't assume anything about the matrices in general. No special symmetry, and they are not always square. Has anyone experienced this? I would hate to resort to using my own hand-coded method. I am using the same options for compiling whether or not I use the hand-coded version of the complex multiply or the one in the library. Perhaps the operation is not inlined??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <vector>

#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int M = 150;
   const int N = 150;
   const int K = 150;

   vector<complex<float>> v1(M*N);
   vector<complex<float>> v2(N*K);
   vector<complex<float>> v3(M*K);

   for (int k = 0; k < M*N; ++k)
   {
      v1[k] = complex<float>(float(k), float(k));
   }

   for (int k = 0; k < N*K; ++k)
   {
      v2[k] = complex<float>(float(k), float(k));
   }

   LARGE_INTEGER frequency, start_time, end_time;

   QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
   QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_time);
   for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
      {
         complex<float> sum(0.0f, 0.0f);
         for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
         {
            int idx1 = i*N + j;
            int idx2 = k*N + j;
            sum += v1[idx1] * v2[idx2];
            //float re = v1[idx1].real() * v2[idx2].real() -
            //   v1[idx1].imag()*v2[idx2].imag();
            //float im = v1[idx1].real()*v2[idx2].imag() +
            //   v1[idx1].imag()*v2[idx2].real();
            //sum.real(sum.real() + re);
            //sum.imag(sum.imag() + im);
         }
         v3[i*K + k] = sum;
      }
   }
   QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_time);
   LARGE_INTEGER elapsed_us;
   elapsed_us.QuadPart = (end_time.QuadPart - start_time.QuadPart) * 1000000 / frequency.QuadPart;
   cout << "Total time in microseconds = " << elapsed_us.QuadPart << endl;
   this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
}
```

Here are the command line options:

/GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Matrix_Multiply_Test.pch"

Comment: Oh Ive seen this exact question before but I cant find the dupe right now, IIRC its just VS that sucks at optimizing it. I'll post it here if I find it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a basic search but I couldn't find anything useful. I was pretty convinced that I must need to enable a setting or something. It's unfortunate the standard committee can't specify performance. I understand why they can't, it's just annoying. I guess I'll look through their header file and see what I can find. What could make the performance so bad? Maybe I can open a defect report?

Comment: Oh oops its not a dupe from SO, I saw something similar [on twitter](https://twitter.com/rygorous/status/558449507822612480)

Answer (score 0):

GCC has the same problem, unless you compile with -O3 -ffast-math. ICC seems to have the problem according to http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2011/Intro%20to%20Intel%20AVX-Final.pdf . (Compare the benchmarks between Complex and Float)

I prefer the hand writen float algorithm for my mandelbrot set demo and don't use std::complex. But for real world problems I don't have an answer.